# I would like to create custom type which contain two years in postgresql, how i could do this?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I would like to create custom type which contain two years in postgresql, how i could do this? only years without months and days

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: i would like create a column which contains two years
and i dont want using integers or chars
i would like to use dates

Comment: repeating the same statement doesn't give more information. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? What do you need those two years for? You might want to add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. **Formatted text** please no screen shots.

Comment: i would to use date type just for satan sake
joke 
dat's a task, to create a type which contains two years and use date type for them 
i dont want to use checks for integers (like it should be positive)

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/MGQJ84204)**

```
CREATE TYPE twoYears AS
   (year1 date,
    year2 date);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;  

CREATE TABLE myTable (
   ty twoYears
);    

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (ROW('2010-01-01', '2020-01-01'));

SELECT (ty).year1,  (ty).year2
FROM myTable;

SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (ty).year1),
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (ty).year2)
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Dat works, but i would like to use dates not integers

Comment: what is the problem? use date instead of integer and save using `yyyy-01-01`

Comment: Ok, thanks. It does not totally fit my task, but it is close

Comment: what else is missing?

Comment: i would like to make it simple for person who selecting values
SELECT (ty).year1,  (ty).year2
FROM myTable;
and he or she will get just two numbers
but probably it is not possible by using dates
so thank, you

Comment: As listed in my example below, daterange is already a type in postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table mytable (rng daterange)
```

daterange is already a type in postgresql.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html

Comment: Although I doubt your professor will give you a good grade on the assignment using it since it's not a custom type. My response would be to come up with an assignment with a real-world need for a custom type rather than something that's this contrived.